# How can I get sets of 2 entries where each set starts with a different letter and no letter is repeated from a sqlite database?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Like this:

```
apple
aardvark
banana
bet
cow
car
...
zipper
zoo
```

Assuming the database has more than just two different entries that start with any of the letters. I was thinking of doing something with TOP and wildcards, but I don't really know enough about SQL to pull this off. What can I do?

Comment: Is the above sample data or your desired output?

Comment: Desired output. The actual data can have any number of entries.

Comment: So what do you mean by 'no letter is repeated'  You want just 2 words per starting letter, not worried about what letters are contained in each word, right?

Comment: Yep! I was having a tough time thinking about how to describe that.

Comment: Can it be the first two records, or do you want random entries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with the `substr` function and a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable a
WHERE wordField IN (SELECT wordField 
                    FROM YourTable AS b
                    WHERE substr(a.wordField ,1,1) = substr(b.wordField ,1,1)
                    ORDER BY wordField
                    LIMIT 2)
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/b34b2/1/0)

You can use the `ORDER BY` to adjust which 2 records are returned. Like `ORDER BY RANDOM()` if that's supported.